# ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from 'plotly.io._json'

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to make a basic Dash app, and I got this error. Here is my code.

```
import dash
import plotly
from dash import dcc
#from dash_core_components.Markdown import Markdown
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import os
import PyPDF2

app = dash.Dash(__name__, meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device- width, initial-scale=1"}], external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SUPERHERO])
app.title = 'FODS'
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([

dcc.Input(
        id='input_text',
        type= 'text',
        placeholder="Enter Unicode Search Phrase".format('text'),
    ),

html.Div(id = 'output-area')

])


@app.callback(
Output('output-area', 'children'),
Input('input_text', 'value'),
)

def return_pages(input_text):

    locations = []
    answers = 'Please refer '

    for file in os.listdir('./Solutions'):
        path = './Solutions/' + file
        pdfFileObj = open(path, 'rb')

        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj, strict = False)

        for i in range(pdfReader.numPages):
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)

            text = str(pageObj.extractText())   
            if input_text in text:
                locations.append([file, i+1])
                answers += file + ', at page ' + str(i + 1) + ', '

    if len(locations) != 0:
        return answers + ' for your answers'

    else:
        return 'Sorry, your query fetched no answers'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[Screenshot of the error on local development server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxRc6.png)

I have tried updating the libraries and restarting the venv. Please advise on what can be done. There is a slight time crunch on this project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it in a non-anaconda environment?